Swift - iOS 18.0/ iOS 18.0.1 UITabBarController Child View Controller Incorrectly Added as UITabBarItem, Leading to Application Crash
I have encountered a problem in iOS18.0/ iOS18.0.1, I only create 3 UITabBarItem，but there shows 4 Item, when click the empty item, the app crashed. what happened？how to solve it？I have searched a lot of information but did not find a solution. The specific performance is shown in the figure.enter image description here
